# How can I align memory on the heap (in a box) in a convenient way?

Tags: rust, alignment, heap-memory

I'd like to align my heap memory to a specific alignment boundary. This boundary is known at compilation time. Anyhow, the `Box` abstraction doesn't allow me to specify a certain alignment. Writing my own `Box`-abstraction doesn't feel right too, because all of the Rust ecosystem uses `Box` already. What is a convenient way to achieve alignment for heap allocations?

PS: In my specific case I need page alignments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If nightly is acceptable, the `Allocator` api provides a fairly convenient way to do this:

```
#![feature(allocator_api)]

use std::alloc::*;
use std::ptr::NonNull;
struct AlignedAlloc<const N: usize>;


unsafe impl<const N: usize> Allocator for AlignedAlloc<N> {
    fn allocate(&self, layout: Layout) -> Result<NonNull<[u8]>, AllocError> {
        Global.allocate(layout.align_to(N).unwrap())
    }
    unsafe fn deallocate(&self, ptr: NonNull<u8>, layout: Layout) {
        Global.deallocate(ptr, layout.align_to(N).unwrap())
    }
}

fn main() {
    let val = Box::new_in(3, AlignedAlloc::<4096>);
    let ptr: *const u8 = &*val;
    println!(
        "val:{}, alignment:{}",
        val,
        1 << (ptr as usize).trailing_zeros()
    );
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=35b2502a8d711513705949cb825565b4)

If you wanted you could also add support for using other allocators or choosing the value dynamically.

Edit: Come to think of it, this approach can also be used in stable via the `GlobalAlloc` trait and the `#[global_allocator]` attribute, but setting an allocator that way forces all allocations to be aligned to that same alignment, so it would be fine if you needed to ensure a relatively small alignment, but it is probably not a good idea for a page boundary alignment.

Edit 2: switched from using the `System` allocator to the `Global` allocator, because that's bundled in with the `allocater_api` feature, and it is a more sensible and predictable default.

Comment: This is super awesome! Thanks a lot, how cool! Is there any official documentation for that yet? I'm quite familiar with (nighty) Rust, but never heard of this.

Comment: @phip1611 The documentation for the trait can be found [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/alloc/trait.Allocator.html), and the unstable book entry is [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/unstable-book/library-features/allocator-api.html). Various allocator API methods can be found in the relevant struct's documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what data you want to align, you can use [`repr (align)`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/type-layout.html#representations) to specify the alignment of a type. You can either use that directly on your data or use a wrapper struct.

For example, the following will always be aligned on 16 bytes (whether on the heap, on the stack or inside another struct):

```
#[repr (C, align (16))]
struct AlignedBuffer([u8; 32]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Posting an alternative answer just in case folks are curious. I'm not a Rust export but this seems to work:

- https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=4c2d9c936e2755d1fc835d1e4663ec8b

```rust
#![feature(allocator_api)]
use std::{
    alloc::{Layout, alloc_zeroed, handle_alloc_error}
};

const PAGE_SIZE: usize = 8192;
const NUM_PAGES: usize = 1000;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Pool {
    frames: Box<[[u8; PAGE_SIZE]; NUM_PAGES]>
}

impl Pool {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
            frames: unsafe {
                let layout = Layout::from_size_align(NUM_PAGES * PAGE_SIZE, PAGE_SIZE).unwrap();
                let ptr = alloc_zeroed(layout);
                if ptr.is_null() {
                    handle_alloc_error(layout);
                }
                let ptr = ptr as *mut [[u8; PAGE_SIZE]; NUM_PAGES];
                Box::from_raw(ptr)
            },
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is UB as the automatic dealloc on drop has a different alignment, the alignment of u8 to be exact. Some Allocator implementations may not work with this approach and panic on the confusing deallocation.

Comment: What's the proper way to do the above, just to add a "Drop" impl?

Comment: I guess something like: Use a type with `#repr(C, align(4096))` that has a single member `bytes: [u8; 4096]`. If the T in Box is of this type, the deallocation layout should be fine.

Comment: Ah, thank you, solid idea