# What is the difference between the allocators "Global" and "System"?

Tags: rust

The Rust standard library provides two allocator structs: `std::alloc::{System, Global}`.
What's the relation and the difference between them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Please note that the following explanations focus on Rust 1.60 nightly. Some things might change, when the new [allocator_api](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/32838) feature gets stabilized.*

TL;DR: `std::alloc::System` glues the standard library types that need memory allocations to the memory allocation mechanism of the operating system (such as: libc: malloc -> brk()/mmap()). `alloc::alloc::Global` is
the default implementation for the `allocator_api` feature, which can be used to alter allocations of Vectors, Boxes, etc.

---

Whereas `std::alloc::System` actually comes from the standard library, `std::alloc::Global` is in fact a re-export from `alloc::alloc::Global`.

When you register a custom global allocator, you need a type that implements the trait `core::alloc::GlobalAlloc`. When you assign this type to a global static variable with the `#[global_allocator]` attribute, Rust lets the following "magic symbols" point to the corresponding implementations of the trait functions.

```rust
extern "Rust" {
    // These are the magic symbols to call the global allocator.  rustc generates
    // them to call `__rg_alloc` etc. if there is a `#[global_allocator]` attribute
    // (the code expanding that attribute macro generates those functions), or to call
    // the default implementations in libstd (`__rdl_alloc` etc. in `library/std/src/alloc.rs`)
    // otherwise.
    // The rustc fork of LLVM also special-cases these function names to be able to optimize them
    // like `malloc`, `realloc`, and `free`, respectively.
    #[rustc_allocator]
    #[rustc_allocator_nounwind]
    fn __rust_alloc(size: usize, align: usize) -> *mut u8;
    #[rustc_allocator_nounwind]
    fn __rust_dealloc(ptr: *mut u8, size: usize, align: usize);
    #[rustc_allocator_nounwind]
    fn __rust_realloc(ptr: *mut u8, old_size: usize, align: usize, new_size: usize) -> *mut u8;
    #[rustc_allocator_nounwind]
    fn __rust_alloc_zeroed(size: usize, align: usize) -> *mut u8;
}
```

There exist higher-level Rust wrappers for these magic functions: 
`alloc::alloc::{alloc, alloc_zeroed, dealloc, realloc}`.

`std::alloc::System` is the default `#[global_allocator]` allocator for the target you are compiling for (Unix, Windows, ...). For example, on UNIX-systems it will use `libc::malloc`, which will use `mmap()` and `brk()` syscalls to obtain heap memory from the operating system.

`alloc::alloc::Global` however is part of the `allocator_api`-feature which can be seen as a finer-grained selection of an allocator that should get used. The Allocator API brings the trait `alloc::alloc::Allocator` that gets implemented by `alloc::alloc::Global`. By default, it forwards requests to `alloc::alloc::{alloc, alloc_zeroed, dealloc, realloc}`. Typical types provided by the `alloc` crate (Vector, BTreeMap, Box, ...) all allow to chose a custom `alloc::alloc::Allocator`. The default value for this is `alloc::alloc::Global`.

To give an example, this is the type definition of `alloc::vec::Vec` (note the "Global):

```rust
pub struct Vec<T, #[unstable(feature = "allocator_api", issue = "32838")] A: Allocator = Global> {
    buf: RawVec<T, A>,
    len: usize,
}
```

You can use custom allocators (the allocator_api-feature) for example to force [page-aligned allocations in a `Box<T>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69544158/2891595).